# How to get Values from HTML String in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem that I want to get different values from different tags from HTML String as, `<p><div class=\"image_wrapper\" style=\"width:320px;\"><img name=\"tccimg_100322484_s\" **title=\"2011 Chevrolet Corvette 2-door Coupe Z06 w/2LZ Angular Front Exterior View\"** src=\"http://images.thecarconnection.com/sml/2011-chevrolet-corvette-2-door-coupe-z06-w-2lz-angular-front-exterior-view_100322484_s.jpg\" alt=\"2011 Chevrolet Corvette 2-door Coupe Z06 w/2LZ Angular Front Exterior View\" width=\"320\" height=\"240\" /><p>2011 Chevrolet Corvette 2-door Coupe Z06 w/2LZ Angular Front Exterior View</p><a name=\"tccwrp_100322484\" class=\"enlarge\" href=\"/image/100322484_2011-chevrolet-corvette-2-door-coupe-z06-w-2lz-angular-front-exterior-view\" target=\"_blank\">Enlarge Photo</a></div></p>\n<p>The <a href=\"http://www.thecarconnection.com/make/chevrolet,new\" class=\"nwslinks_visible\">Chevrolet</a> Corvette is an American icon: a rear-wheel drive, two-seat sports car that started its legendary run in 1953 and has seen 57 years of continuous production in Flint, Michigan, St. Louis, Missouri and most recently in Bowling <a href=\"http://www.thecarconnection.com/category/green,new\" class=\"nwslinks_visible\">Green</a>, Kentucky. Over the years it has constantly evolved to lead performance and value, with occasional lows and numerous highs along the way. Though it has little domestic competition, cars as disparate as the Dodge Viper, <a href=\"http://www.thecarconnection.com/overview/porsche_boxster_2012\" class=\"nwslinks_visible\">Porsche Boxster</a> and 911, and the <a href=\"http://www.thecarconnection.com/overview/nissan_gt-r_2012\" class=\"nwslinks_visible\">Nissan GT-R</a> and 370Z can be considered rivals in terms of performance and/or price. The Chevrolet Corvette is priced from $48,000 to $56,000 for the standard Coupe and Convertible, from $58,000 to $68,000 for the Grand Sport, from $75,000 to $82,000 for the Z06, and from $106,800 for the ZR1.</p>\n<p>Over the past 57 years of production, there have been six generations of Corvette. The first 1953 models featured solid rear axles and inline six-cylinder engines, though in 1955, the V-8 became standard. When the second generation \"Sting Ray\" debuted in 1963, independent rear suspension was added and output was increased to 360 horsepower. A big-block 6.5-liter model was added in 1965, before the famous 427 cubic inch (7.0-liter) engine joined in 1966. The third-gen car began its run in 1968, running for 13 years until 1982--the longest run of the various Corvette generations. The new, fender-flared body style was the primary new addition to the line, along with a three-year run for the ZR-1 performance edition, though emissions and fuel regulations conspired to restrict power output and potential of Corvettes throughout the 1970s. The fourth-generation Corvette hit the street in 1983 as a 1984 year model, bringing with it a complete redesign of the car aside from the engine, with a sleek, modern design and digital instruments, and the second ZR-1 performance version. The fifth-gen car, introduced in 1997, saw another major upgrade, with improved build quality, more performance, and better handling the result. The Z06 model was introduced in 2001, and engines continued to be upgraded, producing 405 horsepower in the Z06.</p>\n<p>The sixth and current Corvette generation debuted in 2005, and brought with it all new bodywork and improved suspension. Power climbed to 400 horsepower for the base Corvette initially, now up to 430 horsepower from its 6.2-liter V-8 LS3 engine, and 505 horsepower for the current 7.0-liter Z06. The ZR1 was added back to the lineup in late 2007 as a 2008 year model, producing 638 horsepower from a supercharged 6.2-liter V-8 engine. Currently available in Coupe, <a href=\"http://www.thecarconnection.com/category/convertible,new\" class=\"nwslinks_visible\">Convertible</a>, a Grand Sport version with upgraded brakes and special bodywork, the high-performance Z06, and the supercar-rivaling ZR1.</p>\n<p>The Coupe and Convertible are the standard Corvettes, with 430 horsepower output and all the conveniences of a modern car, including available Bluetooth on some models, a choice of six-speed manual or automatic transmission, and available leather interior. The Grand Sport is also available as both a coupe and convertible, though the coupe gets a few performance upgrades over the soft top, including a dry-sump oil system when equipped with the six-speed manual transmission, plus the upgraded brakes and flared fenders that both variants get. The Corvette Z06 ups the performance ante with extensive use of carbon fiber body panels and components, an aluminum frame, and a 505-horsepower engine. The ZR1 is king of the hill, its massive power output combined with Brembo ceramic carbon brakes, visible carbon fiber weave components, and a 205-mph top speed. Despite their huge power and impressive performance figures, the brawny engines in the Corvette enable it to achieve up to 26 mpg on the highway.</p>\n<p>No major changes were made for the 2012 model year, though the range did get interior updates, new technology packages, and a range of new exterior colors. High-performance Z06 and ZR1 models also got new performance packages.</p>\n<p>For 2013, a new 427 Convertible Collector Edition has been added, pairing the Z06's LS7 V-8 engine with a Corvette Convertible chassis and unique 60th Anniversary touches. A 60th Anniversary Package will also be available on all 2013 model Corvettes, adding a special touch to celebrate six decades of the Corvette. The  rest of the line carries forward largely unchanged from last year.</p>\n<p>The next major generational upgrade is expected to come in late 2013, with the seventh-generation car drawing on GM's global resources for its new design--the first time the Corvette team has looked outside the U.S. for the iconic 'Vette.</p>\n"`

I want to get Image title value from this html string in the starting, but I am unable to get that. I am using Jsoup for parsing of this HTML String as,

**Code:**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements element = doc.getAllElements();
        for(Element e: element)
        {
            Elements str = e.getElementsByTag("img");
            for(Element el: str)
            {
                String title = el.getElementsByAttribute("title").text();
                System.out.println("The Title:"+title);
            }
        }
```

Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us what your current is doing/not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
String title = el.getElementsByAttribute("title").text();
```

with

```
String title = el.attr("title");
```

Explanation: the function call `getElementsByAttribute("title")` will return a List of Elements (see [Jsoup Doumentation - Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)), when really you just want to look at the attribute for a specific element. See also [Jsoup Documentation - Node](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29).